# Reverse a derivative

Tags: derivatives

This is from reading a book on probabilities.

How is (3) developed?

The text reads:

From

$$(+Δ)−()=−()()Δ\tag{1}$$

We take limits

$$\frac{()}{}=−()()\tag{2}$$

Thus we have

$$()=^{−\int_0^t\lambda(\tau)(\tau)}\tag{3}$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the method of **integrating factors** for solving first-order ODEs? (Because that's what has been used.)

Comment: (Also, the conclusion is only true if $V(0)=1$. Otherwise you need a factor $V(0)$ on the right-hand side.)

Comment: @Hans Lundmark, Why is that?

Comment: Well, what do you get if you let $t=0$ in equation (3)?

Comment: @Hans Lundmark, If t=0, is it like this: $V(0) = e^{-(\lambda(0)-\lambda(0))}=1$?

Comment: Yes, if you replace $\lambda(0)$ with $\Lambda(0)$, where $\Lambda$ is an antiderivative of $\lambda$. Or just use that $\int_0^0$ is zero no matter what you are integrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use an integrating factor (since this is a first order linear ODE), as other comments suggested, or you could notice that $$(\ln y)'=\frac{y'}{y}$$So in this example,  $$\frac{V'(t)}{V(t)}=-\lambda(t)\Rightarrow \ln\left|V(t)\right|=-\int \lambda(t)\, dt+c$$ and depending on your constraints and your initial conditions, $$V(t)=\exp\left(-\int \lambda(t)\, dt\right)$$

Comment: Could you please explain the limited-integral part?

Comment: @kon gram, thanks!  I understand it now.